# Adding popup notice before action

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I couldn't find an answer for this so please forgive if it has been answered elsewhere. I have this function which is displaying "Mark Shipped" link on the frontend. So when clicked on "Mark Shipped" the order is marked as shipped automatically. What I want to do is to add a little popup window "Are you sure?" when clicked on the "Marked Shipped" link, before actually marking order as shipped. And then if user clicks on "yes" to mark order as shipped. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
if ( __( 'No', 'wcvendors-pro' ) == $shipped ) { 
                        $row_actions['mark_shipped'] = array( 
                            'label'     => __( 'Mark Shipped', 'wcvendors-pro' ), 
                            'url'       => '?wcv_mark_shipped='.$order->get_order_number() 
                        ); 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with jQuery, with a widget called dialog. Check this on:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did it, tank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can accomplish that with PHP only. Unless you create another page just for asking the user yes/no.

I believe the proper solution would be to add onclick event to that button/link in order to call JS/jQuery function that will load the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event on the client-side, I personally, if using Bootstrap will use modals ([learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)), or use jQuery dialogs.

In order to achieve this in Bootstrap, merely create the modal, then if paid, trigger the function client-side, a function to open the modal can be as simple as this:

```js
function triggerPaidModal() {
  $('#modalID').modal('show');
}

function closePaidModal() {
  $('#modalID').modal('hide');
}
```

It'll work successfully with that, if you're using Bootstrap, otherwise try jQuery dialog, which is [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this as everything is written in php, so don't know where to place this code.. I'm using wordpress between..